# jQuery catch value return [object Object] codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am getting an error when I am trying to pass a value from `controller` to `view`

**My Controller**

```
function showMonitoringlp(){        
    $data['periode_laporan'] = 'data';
    $data['periode_tindak_lanjut'] = $this->input->get('periode_tl_awal');
    $data['NoJudulLaporan'] = $this->input->get('NoJudulLaporan');
    $this->load->view('V_monitoring_laporan',$data);
}
```

**V_monitoring_laporan**

```
var d1 = $('#periode_laporan_awal').val('<?php echo $periode_laporan ?>'); 
var d2 = $('#periode_tl_awal').val('<?php echo $periode_tindak_lanjut ?>'); 
var d3 = $('#NoJudulLaporan').val('<?php echo $NoJudulLaporan ?>');    
alert(d1);
```

It always return to `[object Object]`.

Is there something wrong with my syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than one problem with the code you have shared here, like this line is assigning data string to array `$data['periode_laporan'] = 'data';` Here `data` is just a string.

And you are trying to assign that string to a `#periode_laporan_awal` using val(), and this whole sentence is assigned to var d1, so obviously it will return `[object object]` because it is returning the whole element as JS object.

Comment: how do i fix that ?

Comment: What you want to achieve ?

Comment: Happy to help. :-)